# how can i calculate value form props in Vuejs components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i want to increase and decrease `<test :test="{{ $my_cart['cart_quantity'][$i] }}"></test>` that i get form props in Vue components

this is my component

```
Vue.component('test',{
props: {
```

and this is HTML tag

Comment: You have invalid Vue2 syntax in `:test`. Is this a vue 1 project?

Comment: Are you mixing php and javascript/vue?
Where does `$my_cart` come from?

Comment: sorry everyone i had a problem when i was making this question, it would be nice if you see my code in this link, thankyou for answer, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257817/how-can-i-increase-decrease-value-from-props-in-vuejs-components?noredirect=1#comment75526337_44257817